# Why aren't my last split patterns respected in this code

Tags: java

First thing first, here is my code:

```
String line = "Events|1005435529|7021370073||PAGELOAD|2017-06-19T12:04:40||JI||ServerHostName|ServerIPAddress|9P2_D2jB9Toct7PDTJ7zwLUmWfEYz6Y4akyOKn2g4CepveMH4wr3!46548593!1497854077121|||||||||||";
int offset = line.indexOf("Events");
String zeroIn = line.substring(offset);
String[] jsonElements = zeroIn.split("\\|");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(jsonElements));
```

Output:

```
[Events, 1005435529, 7021370073, , PAGELOAD, 2017-06-19T12:04:40, , JI, , ServerHostName, ServerIPAddress, 9P2_D2jB9Toct7PDTJ7zwLUmWfEYz6Y4akyOKn2g4CepveMH4wr3!46548593!1497854077121]`
```

I also notice spaces added to each array element at the beginning.

My question is that I have almost 10 empty pipeline symbols at the end of the String `line` while as the first second and third occurance of empty pipeline symbols is respected, the last ones are missed and don't add up in the array. What do I miss here?

Comment: You already got an answer regarding the empty elements. To answer the other question, *there are no extra spaces* added to each array element. It just *prints* like that for better readability. If you print a single element, you will see that there is no space at the beginning. You can also see this by observing the first element in your output, `Events`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[split(java.lang.String regex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) calls [split(java.lang.String regex ,int limit)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) with an argument of 0.

> If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as
>   possible, the array can have any length, and **trailing empty strings**
>   **will be discarded**.

You may call this method by yourself with a positive value (and large enough to be sure to include all tokens) to prevent empty tokens from being discarded :

```
String[] jsonElements = zeroIn.split("\\|", zeroIn.length());
```

**Note** : from the comments below, using a negative value is indeed a better way to do this :

```
String[] jsonElements = zeroIn.split("\\|", -1);
```

> If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as
>   possible and the array can have any length.

Comment: Since you're citing the documentation you should use a negative limit.

Answer (score 3):

From `String` class and `split` method [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-):

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

So, after last occurrence of not empty string, rest will be not included in array.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer explains the limitations you oberved splitting on a single character delimeter.  I thought I would offer this answer if you need the ability to retain empty tokens in your output.  If you split using a lookaround, e.g. a lookbehind, then you would end up with distinct entries even when two pipes have nothing in between them:

```
String line = "Events|1005435529|7021370073||PAGELOAD|2017-06-19T12:04:40||JI||ServerHostName|ServerIPAddress|9P2_D2jB9Toct7PDTJ7zwLUmWfEYz6Y4akyOKn2g4CepveMH4wr3!46548593!1497854077121|||||||||||";
String[] parts = line.split("(?<=\\|)");
for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that every part will contain its `|` since it is no longer the delimiter. I also think this is the reason why the last parts will be returned (they're no longer empty strings), rather than being distinct entries.

Comment: I am running under a lot of load, while as your answer might solve my issue I think adding a 'more than one char' regex will slow down my program. I havent tested this though but by general reading on the internet, split patterns greater than one char length are converted into a regex which is equal to your answer.